# How to log in to a website with python?

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, urllib2, python-requests

I'm currently trying to write a python script to log in to a website.
Access requires an email and password.

Which module is best for this? 
My current script uses the requests module, but is unsuccessful as the websites source code retrieved shows the following status:

**ERROR**

```
</title></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Base variables
    var IsLoggedOn = false;
    var CurrentUserId = 0;
    var EventFollowingHash = 6864;
    var AjaxSource = 'http://www.iex.nl';
</script>
```

**Here's my code:**

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "WEBSITE URL"
    USERNAME = "VALID EMAIL"
    PASSWORD = "VALID PASSWORD"

    c.get(url)

    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, next='/')
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer":"WEBSITE URL"})
    page = c.get("PROTECTED LAYER OF WEBPAGE")

    print page.content
```

Help welcome, this one's been troubling me for a while!!

Comment: It's often helpful to use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to look at the HTTP request and see exactly what the POST data is as well as cookies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out urllib2 (documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html). There is quite a bit of information here (especially the related article link) on basic authentication. I can't really elaborate with code without knowing more about the specific scenario that you are facing, but the examples on these pages should get you well on your way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the site is using basic auth (which it might not be, but you have not specified) than you will find this page helpful (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) basically, you pass the credentials with the auth parameter on your get request.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there is an easier way to do this using Python's mechanize module (use easy_install to install it).

I wrote a trading algorithm a while back that used mechanize & Python to log into and out of my simulator account.

First things first, you have to find the "name" attributes of the email and password inputs on the website. Let's say the name attribute for email is "email" and the name attribute for password is "password." Also, let's say the name attribute for the form itself is "form" and the name attribute for the submit button is "submit"

Your code should look something like this:

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = "the url of the login page"
br.open(url)

#you have to select the form before you can input stuff to it
browser.select_form(name="form")

br.form["email"] = "your username"
br.form["password"] = "your password"

#you have to "select" the submit button by its name attribute
br.form["submit"]

#submit the form
br.submit()

#open the login-protected page
br.open(trade_url)

#do whatever you want with the page now that you've gained access
```

Remember, you have to install mechanize before you run the above code. Refer to easy install or the mechanize docs [here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: Thanks for the help - still no luck unfortunately. 
The mechanize module if installed successfully, however I can't manage to login successfully. 

Here's the website I'm trying to connect to: 
http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk/member/login.aspx

Comment: What happened when it didn't login successfully? Were there any error messages? What name attributes did you use for the form, email, password, and submit buttons?

Comment: No error messages from the code - However, running the script returns the source code from the initial login page, prompting the user to retry. The code contains the initial error shown in my first post. I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean with regards to naming attributes, should these be different to those used in my initial code? Thanks once again

Comment: When I say name attributes, I'm referring to the names given to the email and password inputs. Which ones did you use? I can compare them to what they should be and tell you if you're right or not

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? I'm still struggling to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Sure, just post what you tried so I can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Here's a redirect to my latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046314/log-in-to-www-virtualtrader-co-uk-using-python-requests-or-similar-module 
This should explain my problem in much more detail - really struggling with this one!

Comment: What does your mechanize code look like? I'm only familiar with that - not the requests module. Also, what error do you get when you run the mechanize code?

Comment: For your mechanize code (looking at this pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/rgpgmUiv) the problem with your code is that you did not put an "http://" in front of your url. For some reason, you need the full url (http://www.google.com) not just www.google.com to use mechanize on that site.

Comment: After amending the 'http://' issue I'm still faced with an error, which reads: http://pastebin.com/e5E4rsDj

Comment: Change "browser" in line 8 to "br" (like all the others) and see what happens

Comment: Updated code, which appears to have solved the previous issue; unfortunately, now an updated error: http://pastebin.com/e5E4rsDj
The error would suggest I'm attempting to post information to the wrong forms, How can I check this? Thanks once again!

Comment: I've added another few lines to display all forms on the page: See updated code: http://pastebin.com/e5E4rsDj This includes a large body of text, which I'm unsure what to make of. Are you aware of what this is?

Comment: From what I understand, that's actually not your error, which is actually much simpler. In line 17, you put "ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtPassword=" as your name attribute. Get rid of the equals sign at the end of the name attribute.

Comment: I've amended line 17 as you suggested: http://pastebin.com/e5E4rsDj -  and after analysis of the returned source have changed it to 'ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtPasswordDummy' as this successfully changes the stored value. I've commented line 21 as this returns an error; unable to locate. I fear lines 935 - 940 may be the issue, the form submission looks to contain Javascript which Mechanize will not support, is there a way to navigate this? Thanks yet again, hopefully we can crack this one!

Comment: You seem to be correct - the submit button uses javascript, which would make mechanize useless. As a last ditch effort, I would use headless selenium, which would interact with javascript. I'm not familiar with that, but here's a link to help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL7gyuqkzzU

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll be sure to check this beforehand in future! Thanks very much for your help - I'll definitely pursue this one and keep you posted!