# Log in to www.virtualtrader.co.uk using python requests or similar module?

Tags: python, debugging, urllib2, mechanize, python-requests

I'm trying to log in to the [Virtual Trader](http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk) website using the python requests module - 
I have limited experience in this area so would appreciate some help.

**Previously I have used the following code to log in to a similar website:**

```
import requests

USERNAME = 'VALID EMAIL'
PASSWORD = 'VALID PASSWORD'

page = {
    'index':'http://www.bullbearings.co.uk/',
    'login':'http://www.bullbearings.co.uk/login.php',
    'trade':'http://www.bullbearings.co.uk/stock.trade.php?epic=',
    'portfolio':'http://www.bullbearings.co.uk/stock.portfolio.php'
    }

def login(access):    
    with requests.Session() as c:

        c.get(page['login'])

        login_data = dict(email = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, submit = 'Login', cookie = 'yes')
        c.post(page['login'], data = login_data, headers = {'Referer': page['index']})
        source = c.get(page[access])

        print source.content
```

.. I've attempted to deploy similar code to automate login for the [Virtual Trader](http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk) site, however have so far been unsuccessful. My amended code is shown below - I have withheld personal information from each of the examples for security reasons - Accounts can be opened in a matter of minutes for testing purposes, alternatively solutions can be submitted back to this post and I'll be on hand to test if it works and report back.

**Attempt to modify code for use with [Virtual Trader](http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk)**

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk/member/login.aspx'
    USERNAME = 'VALID USERNAME'
    PASSWORD = 'VALID PASSWORD'

    email  = 'ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtEmail'
    password = 'ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtPassword'


    c.get(url)

    login_data = dict(email = USERNAME , password = PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data = login_data, headers = {'Referer': 'http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk'})
    page = c.get('http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk/member/personal.aspx')

    print page.content
```

This one has beaten me! - I'd really appreciate any help trying to solve this. 
Personally I prefer using the python requests library, however if you are able to solve this using an alternative I would be glad to change.

I appreciate this is a very specific question - sorry! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps [selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings) would be better suited to this task?

Comment: Are you able to provide a code example?

Comment: In a few hours, I'd be happy to.

Comment: Thanks, do you require anymore information?

Comment: You want to merely login?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
from selenium import webdriver

USERNAME = 'VALID USERNAME'
PASSWORD = 'VALID PASSWORD'

email  = 'ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtEmail'
password = 'ctl00$MiddleContent$LoginForm$txtPassword'
submit_id = 'ctl00_MiddleContent_LoginForm_cmdLogin'
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # could also use firefox, or a bunch of others listed on the homepage of selenium

driver.get('http://www.virtualtrader.co.uk/member/login.aspx')

login_field = driver.find_element_by_id(email)
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id(password)
submit_field = driver.find_element_by_id(submit_id)

login_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
submit_field.click()
```

If you would like further help, leave a comment here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the script works fine; however I intend to deploy the final project on a raspberry pi so will be unable to use any of the browsers listed on the selenium page. Is there a way to avoid this happening without resorting back to another module such as the mechanize or requests packages?

Comment: Could try the remote plugin?

Comment: Potentially; I'd previously hoped to use either the requests or mechanize modules. Are you able to advise on this? Thanks again

Comment: I would advise against using requests for this. Mechanize may be fine, but I don't think it supports DHTML/Ajax.

Comment: Here's my Mechanize code and its result if you're able to look it over - no errors but no success either; http://pastebin.com/4cWbqmJN - Initially, I thought this worked however I noticed a variable in the retuned source stating otherwise:   ' var IsLoggedOn = false; ' and the page is inaccessable

Comment: Mechanize does not support Javascript. Your comment indicates you're dealing with Javascript. Please use selenium with the remote plugin as I suggested above